# JSTL in AJAX does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, jstl

need your help.I want to write some JSTL code like `<C:IF>` in ajax but it doest not work

```
function myfunction(cd){

$("#datatable tbody").empty();
$.ajax({
    url :'/KurirCC/management-user-by-request.html',
    cache :true,
    data :{"kode":cd},
    dataType :"json",
    type : "GET",
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success : function(jsondata){

        $.each(jsondata.data,function(i,obj){
            var status = obj.sts;
            tableHtml ="<tr> <td>"+ obj.id_mobile + "</td> <td>" + obj.nama +"</td> <td>"+ obj.username +"</td> <td>"
            + obj.kota + "</td> <td><c:if test="${status == 1}">Aktiv</c:if></td><td align='center'><button type='button' class='btn tom-history' title='History' ></button></td> </tr>";
            $(tableHtml).appendTo('#datatable tbody');
        }); 
    }

});
```

}

this code `<td><c:if test="${status == 1}">Aktiv</c:if></td>` not work,
where the problem lies?

Comment: This makes no sense. See the duplicate for a basic explanation on how stuff is supposed to work. JavaScript has its own `if ()` statement already. Make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using this code in jsp. In js JSTL tag will not work.
Below correction in your code should solve the problem.

```
  $.each(jsondata.data,function(i,obj){
            var status = obj.sts;
            tableHtml ="<tr> <td>"+ obj.id_mobile + "</td> <td>" + obj.nama +"</td> <td>"+ obj.username +"</td> <td>"
            + obj.kota + "</td> <td>";
<c:if test="${status == 1}">
  tableHtml+="Aktiv";
</c:if>
tableHtml+="</td><td align='center'><button type='button' class='btn tom-history' title='History' ></button></td> </tr>";
            $(tableHtml).appendTo('#datatable tbody');
        });
```

Comment: I Have implement your code but still did not work,so I change into if(status == 1){
               tableHtml+="Aktiv";
              }

Comment: Oops that was a stupid answer. I did not see that status is there in your json response. sorry